# "stand" vs. "stand for"

Tags: phrase-usage, difference, phrases

I heard in the movie Scarface:

> You can't stand for another man to be touching me.

Do people say *stand for someone to do something*?

Also I am not clear on the difference between **stand** and **stand for**, as both can mean *tolerate* or *endure*. What is the difference between **stand** and **stand for** in this particular sense?

> I can't **stand** the way Mom talks to him"
>
> I wouldn't **stand for** that sort of behavior from him, if I were you.

Comment: I feel your first example should not be read as: [can't stand for] another man to be touching me. It should read as: [can't stand] [for another man to be touching me.] in my opinion. It's not demonstrating the usage of "can't stand for", but "can't stand". But I might be wrong, so it's just an FYI.

Comment: @dan You are absolutely right. It is actually a different question from the second half of my post. I only put it there because the two parts are related.

Comment: Remember that scriptwriters intentionally give their characters poor language skills, dialects and accents. Do a google search for Sopranos Malapropisms, they're great!

Answer (score 2):

Good examples of these two phrases getting mixed up.

I can't stand (something) means I intensely dislike something.

I wouldn't stand for that - means I wouldn't accept the way you've been treated, and I'd do something about it.

You can say: I can't stand porridge.

You can't say: I wouldn't stand for porridge.

Comment: Of course you can say *I wouldn't stand for porridge.* You just need the right context. For instance, when talking to a recruitment officer for Quaker Oats: "You might stand for porridge, but I won't. Look for someone else." It's perfectly fine in that context. It means that you won't represent it. (Which is a meaning that you didn't include in your answer.) In fact, the other meaning you gave *also* makes sense. Such as being served porridge at a 3-star restaurant. That's not something I'd stand for.

Comment: Fair enough Jason. However, I'd prefer to say I wouldn't stand for being given porridge. It's not the porridge you find offensive, it's that fact someone insulted you with such a lowly breakfast. Not sure I'd go along with the first argument with that poor Quaker though! They're hardly the offensive sort, after all. I do get the point of I hate everything that (Nigel Farage?) stands for ;-)